# Adding a template question to the Ask Question box

Tags: feature-request

Every now and then we see some questions of very low quality. The question is 70% venting and/or panic and begging and include no information about the device itself or the Android version.

We have [how do I ask a good question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) but let's face it, most newcomers don't read such stuff, even the [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).

Even though I know it won't one hundred percent prevent such things, I think placing a pre-formatted template shadow question might be useful for new and noob users. We already use this method at the [profile parts of our user pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GKDq.png) which *-in my opinion-* needs it much less than the question page.

I'm no psychologist but since people come with the intention of being walked through, I think this can be a way to guide them to ask better formatted questions and thus raise the general quality average of questions.

For example something like this:

```
Your problem: My phone is stuck on a bootloop after rooting with Kingoroot.

Things you tried so far: I tried to boot into recovery however I failed. 

I don't know what else to do


Your phone and Android version: LG G4 with Android M
```

Comment: The `What's your Android question?  Be specific.` guidance in the title field is probably insufficient, I agree.  The body field could definitely use one asking for what they've tried and device details.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thank you. I have actually seen plenty of users with low reps that modified their profiles according to the basic template (including myself). So I actually think that people tend to follow that and it might be useful to raise the general quality.

Comment: About that template, [here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/890/14045) is a good argument that you should consider. I'm fine, however, with a template asking only for Android version, model and root status.

Comment: @Firelord I actually target to have people know *what they should include in their question* rather than enforcing a certain format. Some people don't know what information is relevant to their problem. Some don't even know what information they can/should provide us with. Since people are more likely to accept suggestions when confused, a template might give them the basic idea faster than any other thing, make them generate a high quality question that'll help them solve their problem and be a good addition to our site.

Comment: I believe that this would help newcomers know what to put into their question, so that we can help them in  a much quicker time frame. But my question is will user take this up or just ignore it?

Comment: Can this be only active below a certain rep limit? Say  15 rep? More experienced users shouldn't be affected by this, as it would just waste time for them.

Comment: Should this be active just for people without the Informed badge rather than below a rep figure?  Also, put something similar in the answer box - look at the number of "Me too" and "Have you found the answer yet?" posts we get.

Comment: @SarpSTA That is way better, then I Original thought,  can't try the features out as am on phone at the moment, but visual ly it looks good, one suggestion, maybe, is to add a question Mark next to some of the box's , telling the user where they can find the info E.g Where to find the device model  (although this maybe limited to only people with no knowledge at all of where to find that info). All in all, I be live that this should be implemented on this site

Comment: @Matt07211 I decided to post it as an answer and leave the question itself untouched since Firelord suggested so. If you want to check it out, you can find it in the answer :) Thanks for the positive feedback! I also changed the link to the example since the old sandbox didn't support some HTML functions. I added a JSFiddle link. Check it from there.

Comment: @SarpSTA hopes that this gets implemented

Answer (score 2):

I felt like the idea is found appealing. But little to no contribution is made so I decided that I must visualize the idea so we can brainstorm on a more tangible project.

What I suggest is instead of the classic *title+body* question form format we have right now, a new member will find a different format where the form is divided into different parts. Also, there will be an option to deactivate this suggested new format and activate the classic format instead, however this option will be available only if the user is above a certain reputation (in my opinion 15 reputation would suffice, since that is when a user gets to upvote which means the community trusts this user is able to tell a good post from a bad one.)

You can see [an example of this idea here](http://jsfiddle.net/SarpSTA/qeLepvyp/).

I chose this approach based on comments like these:

> The What's your Android question? Be specific. guidance in the title
>   field is probably insufficient, I agree. The body field could
>   definitely use one asking for what they've tried and device details. –
>   Matthew Read♦

I agree and it was already a part of my initial idea so I implemented it on the example.

> I believe that this would help newcomers know what to put into their
>   question, so that we can help them in a much quicker time frame. But
>   my question is will user take this up or just ignore it? – Matt07211

By forcing this reputation limit we are making sure that they won't be able to deny it.

> Can this be only active below a certain rep limit? Say 15 rep? More
>   experienced users shouldn't be affected by this, as it would just
>   waste time for them. – Tamoghna Chowdhury

Agreed and a supported idea.

> Should this be active just for people without the Informed badge
>   rather than below a rep figure? Also, put something similar in the
>   answer box - look at the number of "Me too" and "Have you found the
>   answer yet?" posts we get. – Chenmunka

I thought reputation is better because you don't need to actually read the tour to get the informed badge. Just holding down on page down button does the job.

Comment: 15 points are way too low. It would beat the purpose of having a feature at all.  Post a two liner one time, make two edits with correcting tags or title and there you go with 15 points. // System trusts you at 125 points with the privilege to vote down to tell what is bad and not with 15 to tell what's good only. // The problem with the example is that all the sites runs more or less the same SE engine. *You're asking for too much work* with that example. No problem here, if they are willing to implement it. // You may still want to think about placeholder. It can be done.

Comment: @Firelord You know what? I literally thought the same about the 125 rep thing but I thought it was too high. But now, I actually think 125 is better since it includes users from other sites with +100 bonus too. For the engine, I don't know about it. If it can't be modified then we can't ask for magic. But I don't agree that it is too much work. It took me 15 minutes to shape it. A proper implementation wouldn't take much more.

Comment: +1 for efforts to present in a *tangible* form